# How to use Authentication object in $http.get().then() AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, authentication

I am trying to use my Authentication object in Angular $http.get async task. How is this done? I think there is some fundamental fact I am not understanding. When I debug this the $http.get isn't run until after everything else. How do I get Authentication information at this point? Is it even possible?

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', '$stateParams', 'Feels', '$http',
        function($scope, Authentication, $stateParams, Feels, $http) {

            // This provides Authentication context.
            $scope.authentication = Authentication;

            var userFeelIds = Authentication.user.feels;

            var userFeelIdsArray = userFeelIds.split(',');

            $http.get('/api/feels').then(function(response) {
                 var test = '';
            }); 

        }
    ]);
```

Comment: you should read this: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can post your Authentication code as well, however the fundamental idea here is that you need to use resolve in your routing.

```
.when('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    resolve: {
        Authentication: function(Authentication) {
            //Not sure what your auth service looks like but I assume there is some init function.
            Authentication.init();
        }
    }
}
```

So this basically tells angular to not load the page until the Authentication service is done loading its data. This is done via promises and luckily, the $http methods all return promises.

So now in your controller you will be certain that the data is loaded.

```
 angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'Authentication',
    function($scope, Authentication) {

        var userFeelIds = Authentication.user.feels;

        var userFeelIdsArray = userFeelIds.split(',');

    }
]);
```